# Why is my RecyclerView is invisible inside ScrollView?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a scrollView in my xml. There's ConstraintLayout inside of it. In the ConstraintLayout is my RecyclerView. It's invisible. When I change ScrollView to ConstraintLayout everything gets back to normal. Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context=".ui.fragments.ChannelAudioFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/allChannelAudiosProgressBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/noAudiosTitle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:text="No audios"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/channelAudiosRefreshSwipe"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rvAllChannelAudios"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I don't get any errors in console. Why is this happening?
**UPDATE**
Additional info: I'm using it in ViewPager. Here it is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".ui.fragments.ChannelFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/channelBlock"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/main_background"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivChannelImage"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_person_flat"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/channelName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Qewbite"
            android:textColor="@color/whiteColor"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:textSize="26sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ivChannelImage" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/subscriptionBlock"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/channelName"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/subscribeButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/subscribed_background"
                android:padding="0dp"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/colorDark"
                android:textColor="@color/whiteColor"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="Unfollow" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/notificationButton"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:tint="@color/whiteColor"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_notification"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/colorDark"
                android:background="@drawable/subscribe_notification_background"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:textColor="@color/whiteColor" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/headerHr"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/colorNavbarGray"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/subscriptionBlock"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            />

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/channelSubscribers"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="10M"
            android:textColor="@color/whiteColor"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/channelSubscribersTitle"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/channelSubscribersTitle"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/headerHr" />

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/channelSubscribersTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Followers"
            android:textColor="@color/colorLightGray"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/channelSubscribers" />

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/channelListened"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="120M"
            android:textColor="@color/whiteColor"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/channelListenedTitle"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/channelListenedTitle"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/headerHr" />

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/channelListenedTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Auditions"
            android:textColor="@color/colorLightGray"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/channelListened" />

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/channelYear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2021"
            android:textColor="@color/whiteColor"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/headerHr" />

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/channelYearTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Year"
            android:textColor="@color/colorLightGray"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/channelYear"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/channelYear"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/channelSubscribers" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/channelBlock"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/channelBlock"
        app:tabRippleColor="@color/colorGray"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/channelViewPager"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tab"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/tab" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably that is because you put more than 1 view inside ScrollView , ScrollView expects 1 view from you. If you want to put more than one consider using a viewGroup view and put your views inside it. For Instance , you can use a vertical LinearLayout to wrap the Views you used. Also , consider using NestedScrollView instead.

Comment: you may try using an Layout view for the outher most ViewGroup instead of scroll view and put the scroll view inside it . Like ScrollView(ConstraintLayout) => ConstraintLayout(ScrollView)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```html
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            >

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/allChannelAudiosProgressBar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                    android:id="@+id/noAudiosTitle"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:gravity="center|left"
                    android:text="No audios"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


                        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                            android:id="@+id/rvAllChannelAudios"
                            tools:listitem="@layout/event_near_items"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                            tools:itemCount="10"
                            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

```html
swipe_refresh.setOnRefreshListener {
            swipe_refresh.isRefreshing = false
           // refresh the list here
        }
```

Comment: It's still isn't scrollable.

Answer (score -1):

Why not try a nested scroll view.

Comment: I just pasted your code in my android studio, the recycler view is visible. and everything seems to work fine